# Snapping guidelines in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm following this [Inkscape Boundary Logo](https://youtu.be/HSivqhZ7SmM?t=173) (Link will start at the right point in time in the youtube demo) where the designer snaps the guideline to the top of the circle.

I'm trying the same thing with snap midpoints of bounding box edges turned on in Inkscape 0.92, however my guideline does not snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the mouse cursor has to be moved directly over the midpoint of the object that you want to snap to use this technique.